# Button with an image without using type="image"

Tags: html, image, button

I want to add a button which looks like an image that I will assign but its type would not be "image". For example:

```
<input type="button" someimagetag="someimagelink" />
```

Not like

`<input type="image" src="" />`

How do I do that?

Comment: Why not just use a `button` element: `<button><img src="path/to/image.png" /></button>`?

Comment: Well, I tried what you said but it does not look in harmony with my image. Also, I'm trying to run a js method when the button is clicked and when it is clicked, it supposed to run in the background. Instead, it posts data by loading the action page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could style it as you would with any other element, using CSS.

Look at Twitter's Bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ any element that uses the 'btn' class will use these styles:

```
.btn {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-image: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear 0s;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF 25%, #E6E6E6);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-color: #CCCCCC #CCCCCC #BBBBBB;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 5px 14px 6px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
```

Keep in mind they use CSS3 declarations to style their elements but you could use a background image just as well.

Comment: It worked by using a background image. Change the style to this:

    background: transparent url(imgpath.jpg) no-repeat center top;

For exact match with the image, width and height are needed to be set.

Comment: glad to hear it worked, would you mind setting my answer as the appropriate one?